# How do you make a url that passes a parameter work in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on registration logic and I can't seem to make the parameter pass in to work properly. The error I get is a 404 page not found. Previously, I also got a “The view didn't return an HttpResponse object" error. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my url from urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/confirm/(?P<activation_key>\d+)/$', 'mysite.views.confirm', name='confirm'),
```

This is my views.py:

```
def confirm(request, activation_key):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        HttpResponseRedirect('/home')

    user = Hash.objects.filter(hash_key = activation_key)
    if user:
        user = Hash.objects.get(hash_key = activation_key) 
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username= user.username)
        user_obj.is_active = True
        user_obj.save()

    HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
```

I send the url with a string that looks like:

```
"Click the link to activate your account http://www.example.com/accounts/confirm/%s" % (obj.username, activation_key)"
```

So the link looks like this:
http://www.example.com/accounts/confirm/4beo8d98fef1cd336a0f239jf4dc7fbe7bad8849a127d847f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. Remove the trailing `/` from your pattern, or make it `/?` so it will be optional.
2. `/d+` will only match digits, and your link also contains other characters. Try `[a-z0-9]+` instead.

Complete pattern:

```
^accounts/confirm/(?P<activation_key>[a-z0-9]+)$
```

Comment: Ok, the trailing slash and regex was a problem, thanks. Now I get this error: The view mysite.views.confirm didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. Any ideas?

Comment: This is the same error I was getting when I had the regex as: accounts/confirm/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$

Comment: You're not actually returning anything. In the lines where you have `HttpResponseRedirect('/home')`, you need `return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` from end of your url:

```
url(r'^accounts/confirm/(?P<activation_key>\d+)$', 'mysite.views.confirm', name='confirm'),
```

or add `/` to end of your link:

```
http://www.example.com/accounts/confirm/4beo8d98fef1cd336a0f239jf4dc7fbe7bad8849a127d847f/
```

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting Page not found (404)